# Create dynamic HTML from Java POJO's using reflections

Tags: java, servlets

I need to create a HTML for the java object. Each field represents a text box in HTML

Right now I am creating dynamic HTML using reflections. I am using reflections to get the fields of the object and create a corresponding HTML text box. Is this a good way to do this? Or there any better way?

Code Snippet for dynamic field creation.

```
String textFieldHTML = "";
    for (String textField : textFields) {
        textFieldHTML = String.format(" Please provide the %s: <input type=\"text\" name=\"%s\"><br><br>",
                textField, textField);
        System.out.println(textFieldHTML);
    }
```

Output HTML is :

```
<input type="text" name="field1"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="field2"><br><br>
```

Comment: jsp is a solution to your problem

Comment: @JoseLuis can we get the fields of an object in JSP to create dynamic HTML?

Comment: JSP is pretty old technology these days. The modern approach is to make an ajax request from javascript to retrieve the data as JSON and then modify the DOM client side.

Comment: @bhspencer Your suggestion doesn't address the original question, and AJAX and JSON would be overkill for what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @GregBrown The question is pretty broad, essentially "how to build HTML based on the structure of a Java object". There are two standard approaches. 1) Build the HTML on the server side, traditionally done with JSP or perhaps velocity templates and 2) Move the data to the client side with AJAX and JSON and build the HTML there with javascript. Take your pick.

Comment: @bhspencer Your comment still doesn't address the question. He's not asking where to render the HTML - he's asking if using reflection to determine what to render is the best option or not. That's a Java-specific (and hence server-specific) question, the answer to which is irrespective of how the results are ultimately presented.

Comment: The problem you face if who has the responsability to write the html of your forms.  You are using servlet, that is ok, of course.  But think that if you need to add validations to this `<input>` tags, your source could be hard to understand, using servlets.  With jsp, you have to write one `<input>` for each field, without reflection.  Other options are jsf, structs, etc.  And of course, the Single Web Page aproach that says @bhspencer, using Ajax and Json.  But is up to you to decide if keep using servlets or move to other solutions.